# Управление вспышкой камеры

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt5

Как управлять вспышкой камеры на Android устройствах из Qt?
Ищется решение исключительно в стиле Qt. Если на данном этапе развития Qt это не возможно тогда, полагаю, решением может являться связка Qt Android Extras C++ + код управления камерой на Java. К сожалению в Java не силен чтобы реализовать этот вариант.

На Qt пробовал следующие варианты:

QML:

```
Torch {
  power: 75       // 75% of full power
  enabled: true   // On
}
```

другой вариант

```
Camera {
  flash.mode: Camera.FlashTorch
}
```

с++:

```
auto* camera = new QCamera(QCamera::BackFace);
QObject::connect(camera, &QCamera::stateChanged, [=](QCamera::State state){
  qDebug() << "state:" << state;
  if (state == QCamera::LoadedState) {
    auto *exposure = camera->exposure();
    qDebug() << "FlashTorch: " << exposure->isFlashModeSupported(QCameraExposure::FlashTorch);
    qDebug() << "FlashOn: " << exposure->isFlashModeSupported(QCameraExposure::FlashOn);
    if (exposure->isFlashModeSupported(QCameraExposure::FlashTorch)) {
      exposure->setFlashMode(QCameraExposure::FlashTorch);
    } else if (exposure->isFlashModeSupported(QCameraExposure::FlashOn)){
      exposure->setFlashMode(QCameraExposure::FlashOn);
    }
    qDebug() << "flashMode:" << exposure->flashMode();
  }
});
camera->load();
```

Оба варианта не работают. Получаю вывод на консоль:

- FlashTorch: false
- FlashOn: true

Но вспышка не включается.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
```

Тестовый стенд:

- Qt Creator 3.5.0 (opensource)
- Qt 5.5.0 (GCC 4.9.1 20140922, 64 бита)
- android 5.0.1
- телефон Samsung GALAXY S4

**Update 11.01.2016:**

Еще одна попытка на QML. Пример взят отсюда [Camera QML Type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-camera.html#deviceId-prop)

```
Item {
  width: 640
  height: 360

  Camera {
    id: camera
    position: Camera.BackFace
    captureMode: Camera.CaptureVideo

    imageProcessing.whiteBalanceMode: CameraImageProcessing.WhiteBalanceFlash

    exposure {
      exposureCompensation: -1.0
      exposureMode: Camera.ExposurePortrait
    }

    flash.mode: Camera.FlashOn

    imageCapture {
      onImageCaptured: {
        photoPreview.source = preview  // Show the preview in an Image
      }
    }
  }

  VideoOutput {
    source: camera
    anchors.fill: parent
    focus : visible // to receive focus and capture key events when visible
  }

  Image {
    id: photoPreview
  }
}

Button {
  text: "Start"
  onClicked: {
    camera.start()
  }
}
```

Comment: Нашел похожий вопрос на оригинальном SO:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-to-turn-on-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android

Comment: @david_I, к сожалению там решение не на qt

Comment: Простите,не заметил метки((

Comment: Проверьте этот репозиторий на github'e: https://github.com/RodgerLeblanc/Flashlight

Comment: @david_I, посмотрю завтра, беглый просмотр натолкнул на некоторые мысли. Сходу код конечно же не заработал, так как этот пример для BlackBerry 10 а не для Samsung. Автор использует Native SDK for BlackBerry 10.

Comment: Я новичек  в разработке под android и другие мобильные платформы,видимо потому и упускаю важные детали мементы в  коде..Жаль,что не смог помочь в решении вашей проблемы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вспышка поддерживается только в режиме видео захвата.

Comment: Вас не затруднит дать более развернутый ответ? Надеюсь мой вопрос интересен не только мне и окажется полезным и другим пользователям. Я пробовал на QML выводить изображение с камеры на экран. Это считается видео-захватом? В этом случае вспышка тоже не включалась.

Comment: да,  считается. Не могли бы вы пожалуйста привести код с видеозахватом (setCaptureMode). Какую камеру вы при этом используете? не фронтальную ли случайно? включен ли ночной режим?

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Камера не фронтальная. Ночной режим не включен так как включен Camera.ExposurePortrait.

Comment: Для наглядности еще раз поправил пример. camera->start() конечно же присутствует, но нажатие на эту кнопку вспышку не включает. Так же отмечу, что после запуска приложения и инициализации камеры (после небольшой паузы) просмотр камеры становится доступен и без вызова camera->start().

Comment: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.user/17920 не факт что код из qml  запустит QCamera, лучше сделать это из С++ кода "Having the QML Camera started doesn’t mean your C++ QCamera is started. They are two independent objects.

You need to call camera->start(). However, it’s not going to work if the camera is already started from the QML side, you need to do the check before starting the camera in QML. Another possibility is to pass the QML camera object to your C++ backend, and retrieve the actual QCamera object being in use"

Answer (score -3):

```
Camera cam = Camera.open();     
Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
cam.setParameters(p);
cam.startPreview();

 <permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
             android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
             android:protectionLevel="normal"
             android:label="@string/permlab_flashlight"
             android:description="@string/permdesc_flashlight" />
```

Comment: я ищу решение для Qt. Это же решение для Java. В Вашем ответе не расшифровывается как этот код можно использовать в Qt и можно ли.